# Setting parameters with decorators vs nested functions

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I need to call a multi-parameter function many times while all but one parameter is fixed. I was thinking of using decorators:

```
# V1 - with @decorator
def dec_adder(num):
    def wrap(fun):
        def wrapped_fun(n1):
            return fun(n1, second_num=num)
        return wrapped_fun
    return wrap

@dec_adder(2)
def adder(first_num, second_num):
    return first_num + second_num

print adder(5)
>>> 7
```

But this seems confusing since it appears to be calling a 2-parameter function, `adder` with only one argument.

Another approach is to use a nested function definition that uses local variables from the parent function:

```
# V2 - without @decorator
def add_wrapper(num):
    def wrapped_adder(num_2):
        return num + num_2
    return wrapped_adder

adder = add_wrapper(2)
print adder(5)
>>> 7
```

But I hesitate to use this approach since in my actual implementation the wrapped function is very complex. My instinct is that it should have a stand-alone definition.

Forgive me if this ventures into the realm of opinion, but is either approach considered better design and/or more Pythonic? Is there some other approach I should consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) should work nicely in this case:

```
from functools import partial

def adder(n1, n2):
    return n1 + n2

adder_2 = partial(adder, 2)

adder_2(5)
```

Its' docstring:

> partial(func, *args, **keywords) - new function with partial application 
>    of the given arguments and keywords.

-- so, you can set keyword arguments as well.

PS

Sadly, the built-in `sum` does not suit this case: it sums over an iterable (in fact, `sum(iterable[, start]) -> value`), so `partial(sum, 2)` does not work.

Comment: This is nice and clean. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution - you can use functools and parametrized decorator:

```
from functools import wraps

def decorator(num):
    def decor(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(n,*args,**kwargs):
            return f(n+num,*args,**kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decor


@decorator(num=2) # number to add to the parameter
def test(n,*args,**kwargs):
    print n


test(10)  # base amount - prints 12
```